# How to save Datatable records into database using single server trip

Tags: ado.net

Is there any way of saving all the records of a DataTable to database , with a single call to database?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using DataSet you could use DataAdapter.Update Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx